# webbrowser1.navigate(Properties.Settings.Default.homepageurl);

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control, visual-studio-2013

I am using the below code to navigate my browser into a page . The homepageurl is saved in settings.

```
webbrowser1.navigate(Properties.Settings.Default.homepageurl);
```

But the browser is not navigating and an error message is shown as "Navigation to webpage was canceled". How can i fix this?

Comment: Have you tried the same url in internet explorer?

Comment: I recommend you to navigate on Internet Explorer into this address and if it also fails, then check these articles: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/181050 and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/813827

Comment: webbrowser1.navigate("http://google.com"); is working. but when i need to save it to Properties.Settings.Default.homepageurl